# How to make python Requests work via SOCKS proxy

Tags: python, proxy, socks, python-requests

I'm using the great [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library in my Python script:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://example.com")
print(r.text)
```

I would like to use a SOCKS proxy, how can I do that? Requests seems to only support HTTP proxies.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The modern way:

```
pip install -U 'requests[socks]'
```

then

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://go.to', 
                    proxies=dict(http='socks5://user:pass@host:port',
                                 https='socks5://user:pass@host:port'))
```

Comment: Beware, when using a SOCKS proxy requesocks will make HTTP requests with the full URL (e.g., "GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" rather than "GET / HTTP/1.1") and this behavior may cause problems. Sadly it seems like there is no better solution available for now.

Comment: Additionally, I have found no way to use username and password in the proxy settings.  Had to resort to urllib2.

Comment: I'm using zsh and I have to do `bash -c "pip install -U requests[socks]"` instead otherwise zsh will complain `zsh: no matches found: requests[socks]`.

Comment: On Windows you also need: pip install win-inet-pton

Comment: @BruceSun `pip install 'requests[socks]'` would be sufficient

Comment: it did change, just all i needed to do was to change "http" to "https" because i'm using torsocks on local machine

Comment: I needed to add an 'h' to the socks URL: `socks5h://localhost:8080` because the hostname could not be resolved on my end.  From https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1035, it seems that the 'h' tells the library that the server will be the one to resolve the hostname.

Comment: pipenv install 'requests[socks]'

Comment: @BruceSun I use zsh too... just use quotations on the packages.. `pip install "requests[socks]"`

Comment: Hi, it's worth noting that `requests[socks]` installs `PySocks` itself. This can be seen in the `setup.py` of `requests` itself - `'socks': ['PySocks>=1.5.6, !=1.5.7']`. So two answers are correct - yours and @Jim

Comment: "socks5" not works correctly for me, I used "socks4" and it works.

Comment: The modern way would be to use `python3 -m pip install -U "requests[socks]"`, since using `pip` directly is discouraged.

Comment: Philippe Carphin's comment was super duper helpful!

Answer (score 78):

In case someone has tried all of these older answers, and is still running into problems like:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
   SOCKSHTTPConnectionPool(host='myhost', port=80): 
   Max retries exceeded with url: /my/path 
   (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSConnection object at 0x106812bd0>: 
   Failed to establish a new connection: 
   [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

It may be because, by default, `requests` is configured to resolve DNS queries on the *local* side of the connection.

Try changing your proxy URL from `socks5://proxyhost:1234` to `socks5h://proxyhost:1234`. Note the extra `h` (it stands for hostname resolution).

[The PySocks package module default is to do remote resolution](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks/blob/010c31bf1ae6cd93449089b73cefb35ca1ff6862/socks.py#L338-L339), and I wasn't sure why [their integration](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/a019c5e9e8ac461111552fdf9aa97899977cccbf/urllib3/contrib/socks.py#L141-L166) was this obscurely divergent, but as a couple commenters have pointed out, [curl works this way](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--socks5).

Comment: That was exactly my issue! Thanks!

Comment: This was the exact issue for me. It was not doing DNS queries through the proxy. As soon as I added the h, everything worked properly.

Comment: Thanks, the `socks5h` approach is *so* much cleaner than the monkey-patching workaround I was worried I'd have to do before.

Comment: Very nice. I could not find `socks5h://` anywhere for Python documentation on proxies. Must have been looking in the wrong places. Gotta love SO.

Comment: @Ligemer sometimes the only right place to look is the code. (But having looked at the code, update StackOverflow, and now there are two right places to look :) )

Comment: On ubuntu 19.10, despite changing to socks5h, I'm still getting this error: ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSConnection object at 0x7faa6c0512d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: I am also still getting the SOCKSHTTPConnectionPool error.

Comment: Thank-you-thank-you-thank-you you're my hero!

Comment: I think Requests works this way because curl [works this way](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--socks5)

Answer (score 71):

As of `requests` version [2.10.0](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#2100-2016-04-29), released on 2016-04-29, `requests` supports SOCKS.

It requires [PySocks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySocks), which can be installed with `pip install pysocks`.

Example usage:

```
import requests
proxies = {'http': "socks5://myproxy:9191"}
requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: `pip install -U requests[socks]`

is enogh

Comment: As of my case, pip install -U requests[socks] alone does not work. pip install pysocks is a must.

Comment: Just like to amend to this, that to force a manual upgrade of your version of `requests` to a version that supports _SOCKS_ (> 2.10.0), run pip: `pip install requests==2.18.4` (2.18.4 at the time of writing this), but check: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests for the latest version (this page should show you in the top header what the latest stable ver. is).

Comment: I'm with @DenMark on this one. My work laptop is a Mac and requests[socks] just abjectly refused to install for me no matter what I tried... pysocks magically fixed everything.

Comment: In my case there are `socks` module name conflict with `qBittorrent`, I need remove/move `~/.local/share/data/qBittorrent/nova3/socks.py` and remove that `socks.pyc`, to solve error message `module 'socks' has no attribute 'create_connection'` and `bad magic number in 'socks':` respectively.

Answer (score 22):

You need install [pysocks](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks) , my version is 1.0 and the code works for me:

```
import socket
import socks
import requests
ip='localhost' # change your proxy's ip
port = 0000 # change your proxy's port
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, ip, port)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
url = u'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=inurl%E8%A2%8B'
print(requests.get(url).text)
```

Comment: Great! It is convenient when I want to use a package(e.g. flickrapi) via socks 5 proxy

Comment: It's not a good way to use socks proxy, because it change the default socket and will make some mistake, so if just test it will be OK, but not for real things.

Answer (score 7):

As soon as python `requests` will be merged with `SOCKS5` pull request it will do as simple as using `proxies` dictionary:

> Update: PR was already merged.

```
#proxy
        # SOCKS5 proxy for HTTP/HTTPS
        proxies = {
            'http' : "socks5://myproxy:9191",
            'https' : "socks5://myproxy:9191"
        }

        #headers
        headers = {

        }

        url='http://example.com/'
        res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

See [SOCKS Proxy Support](https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/2953)

Another options, in case that you cannot wait `request` to be ready, when you cannot use `requesocks` - like on GoogleAppEngine due to the lack of `pwd` built-in module, is to use [PySocks](https://github.com/loretoparisi/PySocks) that was mentioned above:

1. Grab the `socks.py` file from the repo and put a copy in your root folder;
2. Add `import socks` and `import socket`

At this point configure and bind the socket before using with `urllib2` - in the following example:

```
import urllib2
import socket
import socks

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "myprivateproxy.example",port=9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
res=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just run your script with `https_proxy` environment variable.

1. Install socks support if it necessary.

```
pip install PySocks
pip install pysocks5
```

2. Setup environment variable

```
export https_proxy=socks5://<hostname or ip>:<port>
```

3. Run your script. This example makes request using proxy and shows IP-address:

```
echo Your real IP
python -c 'import requests;print(requests.get("http://ipinfo.io/ip").text)'

echo IP with socks-proxy
python -c 'import requests;print(requests.get("https://ipinfo.io/ip").text)'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# SOCKS5 proxy for HTTP/HTTPS
proxiesDict = {
    'http' : "socks5://1.2.3.4:1080",
    'https' : "socks5://1.2.3.4:1080"
}

# SOCKS4 proxy for HTTP/HTTPS
proxiesDict = {
    'http' : "socks4://1.2.3.4:1080",
    'https' : "socks4://1.2.3.4:1080"
}

# HTTP proxy for HTTP/HTTPS
proxiesDict = {
    'http' : "1.2.3.4:1080",
    'https' : "1.2.3.4:1080"
}
```

Comment: Is this how it works in latest Requests version? Without ```requesocks```?

Comment: This is the `proxies` dictionary for latest `requests` pull request, that at this time was not merged already. @see - https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/2953

Answer (score 4):

I could do this on Linux.

```
$ pip3 install --user 'requests[socks]'
$ https_proxy=socks5://<hostname or ip>:<port> python3 -c \
> 'import requests;print(requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip").text)'
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed pysocks and monkey patched create_connection in urllib3, like this:

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, "127.0.0.1", 1080)

def create_connection(address, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                      source_address=None, socket_options=None):
    """Connect to *address* and return the socket object.

    Convenience function.  Connect to *address* (a 2-tuple ``(host,
    port)``) and return the socket object.  Passing the optional
    *timeout* parameter will set the timeout on the socket instance
    before attempting to connect.  If no *timeout* is supplied, the
    global default timeout setting returned by :func:`getdefaulttimeout`
    is used.  If *source_address* is set it must be a tuple of (host, port)
    for the socket to bind as a source address before making the connection.
    An host of '' or port 0 tells the OS to use the default.
    """

    host, port = address
    if host.startswith('['):
        host = host.strip('[]')
    err = None
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        sock = None
        try:
            sock = socks.socksocket(af, socktype, proto)

            # If provided, set socket level options before connecting.
            # This is the only addition urllib3 makes to this function.
            urllib3.util.connection._set_socket_options(sock, socket_options)

            if timeout is not socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT:
                sock.settimeout(timeout)
            if source_address:
                sock.bind(source_address)
            sock.connect(sa)
            return sock

        except socket.error as e:
            err = e
            if sock is not None:
                sock.close()
                sock = None

    if err is not None:
        raise err

    raise socket.error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

# monkeypatch
urllib3.util.connection.create_connection = create_connection
```