# Python SOCKS5 proxy client HTTPS

Tags: python, python-2.7, https, proxy, socks

I am trying to make request through a SOCKS5 proxy server over HTTPS but it fails or returns the empty string. I am using `PySocks` library.

Here is my example

```
    WEB_SITE_PROXY_CHECK_URL = "whatismyipaddress.com/"
    REQUEST_SCHEMA = "https://"

    host_url = REQUEST_SCHEMA + WEB_SITE_PROXY_CHECK_URL
    socket.connect((host_url, 443))
    request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: " + host_url + "\nUser-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11\n\n"
    socket.send(request)
    response = socket.recv(4096)
    print response
```

But it doesn't work, it prints an empty string response.

Is there any way to make HTTPS request through the socks5 proxy in Python ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you mention the libraries you've imported?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601316/how-to-make-python-requests-work-via-socks-proxy

Comment: @AakashVerma thanks the provided solution works fine, please post your comment as an answer

Comment: Okay. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As of requests version 2.10.0, released on 2016-04-29, requests
>   supports SOCKS.
>
> It requires PySocks, which can be installed with pip install pysocks.

```
 import requests

 host_url = 'https://example.com'
 #Fill in your own proxies' details
 proxies={http:'socks5://user:pass@host:port',
          https:'socks5://user:pass@host:port'}
 #define headers if you will
 headers={}

 response = requests.get(host_url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

Beware, when using a SOCKS proxy, request socks will make HTTP requests with the full URL (e.g., `GET example.com HTTP/1.1` rather than `GET / HTTP/1.1`) and this behavior may cause problems.