# Curl equivalent of socks5 hostname in python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to run the following curl command(making a REST API request to a Spark UI) via python requests 2.7:

```
curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:1080 http://website-url:18080/api/v1/applications/
```

I've tried by the method explained [here](https://gist.github.com/jefftriplett/9748036) but it didnt work for me. The curl command on the other hand did.

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080',
}
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: the request module in Python 2.7 and Python 3 have different API. So which Python version are you using ?

Comment: Im using python 2.7

Comment: See this question: [how-to-make-python-requests-work-via-socks-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601316/how-to-make-python-requests-work-via-socks-proxy). If this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601316/how-to-make-python-requests-work-via-socks-proxy/15661226#15661226) doesn't work for some reason try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601316/how-to-make-python-requests-work-via-socks-proxy/33253788#33253788)

Answer (score 1):

use 'socks5h' instead  'socks5'

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:1080',
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:1080',
}
```