# Unable to make python requests over tor ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]

Tags: python, python-requests, tor, socks, torsocks

I am trying to make requests using python requests over tor, but i get the error "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

Here is the code i am using:

```
import requests

def get_tor_session():
    session = requests.session()
    # Tor uses the 9050 port as the default socks port
    session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
                       'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
    return session

# Make a request through the Tor connection
# IP visible through Tor
session = get_tor_session()
print(session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
# Above should print an IP different than your public IP

# Following prints your normal public IP
print(requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
```

I have tried disabling the firewall etc but can't seems to understand the problem, any help would be appreciated. I am using python 3.7 windows 10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601316/how-to-make-python-requests-work-via-socks-proxy then

Comment: socks.ProxyConnectionError: Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy 127.0.0.1:9050: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: the problem i am facing when ever i try to make request using the tor, other then that, requests works perfectly.

Comment: Looks like your proxy isn't running or isn't accepting requests for some reason. You can check network packets with a sniffer, or enable some kind of debug logging at your proxy if it supports that.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, i will look into it and update accordingly.

Comment: @JawadAhmadKhan that should be `requests.Session()` with capital `S`

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the Tor Browser needs to be opened first. More in the link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76662854/how-do-i-set-up-a-proxy-when-i-get-the-message-winerror-10061-using-sel.com) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, yes as already mentioned in the comments, there was something wrong with the proxy.

I changed:

```
session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
                   'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
```

To:

```
session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',
                   'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'}
```

90 to 91 in address and it worked !