# Failed to parse Error Python Requests Proxies

Tags: python, python-requests

Python requests don't connect to the proxies socks5.

```
c.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, proxies=dict(http="socks5://user:" + j, https="socks5://user:" + j))
```

Error:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: socks5://user:13.125.104.9:1080
```

I have already installed requests[socks].

Comment: j is a readline() from proxy list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make python Requests work via socks proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601316/how-to-make-python-requests-work-via-socks-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

It should look like:

```
dict(http='socks5://user:pass@host:port',https='socks5://user:pass@host:port'))
```

if ur socks5 dont use user and pass use just:

```
dict(http='socks5://host:port',https='socks5://host:port'))
```