# How to use Python request through a v2ray(trojan server) proxy?

Tags: python-requests, proxy

I've found the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601316/how-to-make-python-requests-work-via-socks-proxy) but I'm currently using a Trojan server. It didn't come with Username or host IP. It has only the **server address, password and port**. So the following grammer

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://go.to', 
                    proxies=dict(http='socks5://user:pass@host:port',
                                 https='socks5://user:pass@host:port'))
```

won't work for me. Is there a similar code for trojan server? Or is there a way for trojan configurations to fit in the code above?

Also, do I have to (or shouldn't) connect to the proxy client if I'm using the proxies in python code? Or should I put it in PAC mode or something?

There's a ":" in the password, so I assume it could fit in the 'user:pass' part but it didn't. (sorry for how stupid it may sound) But the problem may also caused by the conflict of the client.